# .NET: How to debug or decompile a DanamicMethod with dnSpy?

Tags: dynamic-analysis, .net, dnspy

I have a managed .NET executable that supplies the msil bytecode of a function as raw bytes. It constructs a `DynamicMethod` object, sets the bytecode with `DynamicMethod.DynamicILInfo.SetCode()` and invokes it with `DynamicMetho.Invoke()`.

What is the best way to decompile or step into this DynamicMethod thing? How do I reverse it?

DnSyp doc has this to say:

> Dynamic modules can be debugged (but not dynamic methods due to CLR limitations)

But there has to be a way to deal with it.

I am new to .NET debugging so there might be a simple solution I am missing.

Comment: Flare-On chall 8? ;)

Comment: yes. .NET is entirely beyond me. i have literally opened dnspy for the first time yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug `DynamicMethod`'s using the `EventPipe` API. I've written a library that uses it to allow for code injection via `DynamicMethod` that can be debugged: https://github.com/damieng/DamienG.Library/blob/master/DamienG.Library/Diagnostics/EventPipe/DynamicMethodInjector.cs

First, create a new `DynamicMethodInjector` object:
`var injector = new DynamicMethodInjector("MyTypeName", "MyMethodName");`

Then, add some IL to your `DynamicMethod`:
`injector.AddMethodBody(ILGenerator il);`

You can then invoke the `DynamicMethod` as normal, adding a breakpoint to the `EventPipe.Start` method to avoid hitting the breakpoint before the IL is injected:

`// Inject IL into the process
injector.Inject();`

// Invoke your DynamicMethod
var result = (int)m.Invoke(obj, new object[] { 1, 2 });

Comment: The file https://github.com/damieng/DamienG.Library/blob/master/DamienG.Library/Diagnostics/EventPipe/DynamicMethodInjector.cs is no longer available. Has it been moved elsewhere? Is there another mirror to it?